# Why do paths sometimes use double backslashes?

Tags: asp.net, path, routes

I am building an ASP.NET application.  In some instances, paths seem to use a double backslash instead of a single forward slash.  For instance, the FileManagerFolder object represents its full name like this:

```
~\\Content\\Folders\\
```

Whereas normally I would represent this path as follows:

```
~/Content/Folders/
```

I have seen this before and I have no idea what the purpose of it is.  When I use Url.Content on a path with a double backslash, it converts it to using single forward slashes.

What is the point of using double backslashes instead of single forward slashes?

Comment: \ escapes \ so within a string literal \\ is \. The debugger/visualizer displays a \ as \\ - is that what your seeing?

Comment: I thought that at first but (1) If that is true then why is it using a backslash instead of a forward slash?  And (2) If I set the FileManagerFolder.FullName to a new string and look at it in the debugger it displays the double back slash and then on the next line if I create another new string set to Url.Content(FileManagerFolder.FullName) it has the single forward slashes...